# Is there a standarized way for OpenID Connect identity provider to also be a PGP key server?

Tags: openid, openid-connect, pgp

As I understand, OpenID Connect can be used by a server to prove someones identity to another server using a signed token. For this, identity provider needs to authenticate the user in some way - and generally keep tab on who is who.

On the other hand we have OpenPGP key servers that use HKP HTTP overlay to serve keys.

Is there a standard describing connecting both to provide something similar to PGP Global Directory? A service that not only collects the public key but also validates the ownership and keeps them up-to-date.